# How to resolve 301 redirection in search console of my home page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

[how to solve 301 redirection error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U289m.jpg)

I want to solve this 301 redirection problem even i used canonical

Comment: When exactly does this problem occur? Could you provide a bit more information?

Comment: Need more information, what exactly are you trying to resolve? Also that is a Sucuri redirect so it would be modified on their dashboard.